# How to pass Request object into super call

Tags: node.js, typescript, oop, authentication, nestjs

How can I pass `req` into `cookieExtractor` in NestJS like so:

```
@Injectable()
export class JwtStrategy extends PassportStrategy(Strategy) {
  constructor() {
    super({
      jwtFromRequest: cookieExtractor(req), // I want to pass req here
      secretOrKey: config.get('jwt.secret'),
    });
  }
}
```

```
export const cookieExtractor: JwtFromRequestFunction = (req: Request) => {
  if (req && req.cookies) {
    return req.cookies['access-token'];
  }

  return null;
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't need to. All you should need to do here is set the property as `jwtFromRequest: cookieExtractor`. As the `cookieExtractor` method fulfills the `JwtFromRequestFunction` interface, passport should accept it, and be able to call it later, with no problem at all.